# Role Authorization without Owin Middleware with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, authorization, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have a simple empty web api application created in visual studio and deployed to Azure. My Azure application is protected by 'Authentication / Authorization' through Azure portal with Active Directory:

[image]

Azure App registration that protects my simple web api has also roles defined :

[image]

Authorization works as expected and I get a prompt to log in once I navigate to my site.

Then I add an `[Authorize(Role="SOMEROLE")]` to one of the controllers but I get 401 error.

Looking at my ClaimsIdentity I can see that roles are mapped to `roles` type, but  RoleClaimType is mapped to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` type.

[image]

So, is there a way of achieving this without rolling out a programmatic OWIN `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` but protect my application through Azure Portal instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Please also share the OpenIdConnect configuration, found usually in startup.auth.cs